# Rails Active record joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Inquiry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user , dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :booking , dependent: :destroy


end

class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :inquiries
  

end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookings,  dependent: :destroy
end
```

I have these models where a user can create a property and after that he can do a booking of that property, and after that he can create an inquiry.
On the inquiry index page I want to display a property name through the booking table in which the id property is stored.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: try this
`@inquiries = Inquiry.joins(booking: : property)
In inquiry index page
@inquiries.each do |inq|
inq.booking. property.name # can access property object
end

Comment: what ve u tried so far?

Comment: @inquiries = Inquiry.joins(booking: : property) in inquiries_controller.rb
then in index page:
inq.booking. property.name. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@inquiries = Inquiry.joins(booking: : property)

This worked for me

Comment: Please use a code block (surround code in backticks: `code`)